# the phrase "getting tossed"

Tags: meaning

*Ellie’s attack leads to Joe’s confession getting tossed, which is unconscionable.*

Source: http://www.avclub.com/tvclub/broadchurch-season-two-episode-two-216332

I am not sure how to understand the phrase "getting tossed". Is the meaning of the sentence this: Because Ellie (as the police officer) insulted Joe his confession is open to doubt? (I deduce the meaning on the basis of my knowledge of the plot of TV series Broadchurch.)

Answer (score 4):

tossed = thrown, thrown out.

Specifically in this case, thrown out of court. His confession was no longer admissible as evidence & the jury were instructed to ignore it, as though they had never even heard it.

BTW, she **[assaulted](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/assault_1#assault_1__4)** him, not **[insulted](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/insult_1?q=insult)** - big difference.
She physically attacked him in the interview room, cracking his ribs & bruising his face.
She didn't just call him rude names ;-)

Answer (score 1):

"Tossed" in this context doesn't necessarily mean that the confession is open to doubt; if something is thrown out, it's because of some legal reason that means that the jury isn't even allowed to think about it. Sometimes, the thing that's tossed might be completely credible, but it's still not legal to consider it for whatever reason. All the evidence in a court case is subject to doubt, and the jury considers it to see what's most likely; when something's ruled inadmissible, that means it doesn't *matter* how credible or not credible it is anymore, because the jury no longer gets to make that call.